# Display/Record touches in iOS

Tags: usability-testing

Does anyone know of a way to visualize touch gestures (specifically taps) in iOS? I will be screen recording a usability test using an InVision web prototype, so I need a separate tool rather than an API. I am using an iPad G4 running iOS 9.3, so jailbreaking won't be possible.

[This](http://ryancollins.org/2013/08/30/how-to-record-touches-and-gestures-for-ios-screencasts/) seemed like a promising workaround using Assistive Touch, but I couldn't get it to work (there is no indication of when the touch gesture occurs).

Answer (score 1):

Would http://www.uxrecorder.com/ work for you? I haven't tried it myself but it seems to show taps and other gestures in the screen recordings.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for touch heat maps? I think your best bet is to find an app that records and creates heat maps at once.

Here are some options I found: 
https://www.appsee.com/?cpnid=701b0000000W1Gz
http://appanalytics.io/